# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'constantsModule' : simple hello world script fails with error

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

Using cxfreeze to create a exe file with a simple script named

> 'test.py'

which prints

```
print( 'Hello World' )
```

Running cxfreeze falls with error. I have kept test.py in the location from which I am running cxfreeze.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs if you are using Cx-freeze version 6.1, you can go back to 6.0 or go ahead:

pip install -U git+https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze.git@master

Here you can see the issue:

https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/560

and this:

https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/pull/561